# Unable to get city name using Geocoder

Tags: android, google-geocoder

Hello I am trying to get the city name from my current location, but unfortunately I am not able to.

Could I know if there is a better way to do it ? 
Thank you 
Here is the code :

```
//Getting city name
    try{
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            Log.v(TAG, "City = " + city);
            mLocationLabel.setText(city);
            //System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get city name.", e);
        Log.v(TAG, "Failed to get city name.");
    }
```

Comment: Did you try other locations other than yours? `Address` does not guarantee that it will have all of its data. [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the data of Geocoder depends on the location.

I would get rather many results for testing purpose. Like this:

```
try {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 10);
    if (!addressList.isEmpty()) {
        for (Address address : addressList) {
            String result = address.getAdminArea() != null ? address.getAdminArea() : "?";
            result += " | ";
            result += address.getSubAdminArea() != null ? address.getSubAdminArea() : "?";
            result += " | ";
            result += address.getLocality() != null ? address.getLocality() : "?";
            result += " | ";
            result += address.getSubLocality() != null ? address.getSubLocality() : "?";
            result += " | ";
            result += address.getThoroughfare() != null ? address.getThoroughfare() : "?";
            result += " | ";
            result += address.getSubThoroughfare() != null ? address.getSubThoroughfare() : "?";
            Log.i(TAG, result);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed Geocoding.");
}
```

And I have verified Geocoder's data is not so certain.